# PowerBI API PowerBIEntityNotFound

Tags: api, rest, powerbi, microsoft

Al intentar generear un embed token para insertar reportes de powerBI en mi aplicacion web me encuentro con el siguiente problema `PowerBIEntityNotFound` he leido la documentacion y todo parece estar bien, pero el error persiste, mi configuracion:

Permisos de aplicacion en Azure ActiveDirectory
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se agrego un espacio de trabajo y se le dieron permisos al grupo de seguridad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego obtengo el token de acceso con la siguiente configuracion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando intento obtener el embed token con el siguiente endpoint `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken` lo unico que obtengo es el siguiente error:

```
 "error": {
    "code": "PowerBIEntityNotFound",
    "pbi.error": {
        "code": "PowerBIEntityNotFound",
        "parameters": {},
        "details": [],
        "exceptionCulprit": 1
    }
}
```